# RestTemplate request with braces ("{", "}")

Tags: resttemplate

I want to send request through RestTemplate. But my url has braces ('{', '}'), and therefore I have exception: "Not enough variable values available to expand ...".

I try do it through uri

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath(url);
UriComponents uriComponents = builder.build();
URI uri = uriComponents.toUri();
```

But I got new exception:"protocol = https host = null".

How I can send request with my URL? In URL must be braces.

My code:

```
String url = "https://api.vk.com/method/execute?code=return[API.users.search({"count":1})];&access_token...
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
```

Comment: Rest Template will encode the URL. The only workaround this is to use URI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below code encrypts the uri using `UriComponentsBuilder`, adds query params using `RestTemplate` and also sets `HttpHeaders` if any.

```
public HttpEntity<String> getEntityByUri() {
        String req = "https://api.vk.com/method/execute";

        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(req)
                .queryParam("code",
                        "return[API.users.search({"count":1})]");
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));
        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        return new RestTemplate().exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class);
    }
```

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: this worked for me, alos i changed uriComponent to url